# Building OutsystemsNow for android on Android Studio getting dexException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, outsystems

I've imported the Outsystems Now android app into Android Studio. After several hours of trying to import the project and resolve all module imports. I'm currently getting this error with I can't find out whats wrong.

This is the app i'm trying to build run:
[OutsystemsNow-Android](https://github.com/OutSystems/OutSystemsNow-Android)

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Users/nblocal/Desktop/android_Eclipse/sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/dx --dex --output /Users/nblocal/Desktop/git-OutSystems/OutSystemsNow-Android-master/outsystems-app-android/Outsytems/platforms/android/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/nblocal/Desktop/git-OutSystems/OutSystemsNow-Android-master/outsystems-app-android/Outsytems/platforms/android/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I've search for similar erros and tried most of the solutions presented on stack overflow but none have solved my problem :\

build.gradle:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}

ext.multiarch=false

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
        compile project(subproject)
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode Integer.parseInt("" + getVersionCodeFromManifest() + "0")
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    if (multiarch || System.env.BUILD_MULTIPLE_APKS) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

def getVersionCodeFromManifest() {
    def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
}

def getProjectList() {
    def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    def projects = []
    while (matcher.find()) {
      projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
    }
    return projects
}
```

modules:

build.gradle(CordovaLib):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle(AndroidUniversalImageLoaderLib)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 5
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "generic" answer to this kind of problem is that your project is including multiple libraries and some library appears twice (because it may already be included in one of your included libraries).

In this specific case it appears that the following class is defined multiple times (probably because the library it is part of is included multiple times):

```
android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
```

You can see what libraries your project is using by running the following gradle command:

```
gradle -q dependencies
```

Once you find a duplicated library you can remove it by specifying "exclude" in the dependency section.  Something like the following:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```