# gradle error DexException after adding facebook library

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-facebook

after I added the fb library in the gradle dependences:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'
}
```

I started getting an error on gradle build:

```
dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0This usually occurs because of a library getting referred to twice in the dependencies.

You can run the following command to see all the dependent libraries:

```
gradle -q dependencies
```

You may need to do something like this to prevent the support library from being included twice:

*** Updated to reflect comment

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

See this related question: [Building OutsystemsNow for android on Android Studio getting dexException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28073629/990066)

Comment: this was the answer: compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0')
            {
                    exclude module: 'support-v4'
            }